# What IPA sound is the danish "l"-ish sound as in "sidde"?

Tags: ipa

I have an ASCII system for writing sounds mapped to IPA letters, but I can't figure out what the "l" sound is as in Danish "[sidde](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=sidde&op=translate&hl=en)". It's pronounced sort of like (if I were to try to write it out) "sihlthle". What IPA symbol is that? I don't see it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Danish), and after talking with a Danish speaker, they said it's a unique sound that wasn't represented by some other common IPA stuff I used (represented in an ascii system).

Comment: fyi, there is a standardised ASCII equivalent to the IPA already which is X-SAMPA. For transferability of your project, it may be worthwhile using it, rather than a homebrewed system

Comment: Homebrewed system is much better and more user friendly than X-SAMPA. I have not met anyone who uses X-SAMPA or IPA for writing pronunciations. I have seen the results, so someone is doing it, but very small proportion of speakers know how to do it, let alone what it is or having the desire to learn it.

Comment: @LancePollard IPA is absolutely not reserved for “the most hardcore people”. My seventh-grade French textbooks all had pronunciations in IPA. Wikipedia uses IPA (with help files, but still). Most dictionaries use IPA. Even tourist parlours often use IPA. It is by far the most common way of writing pronunciations. Also, it is there on the IPA for Danish, given as just plain /ð/, which is fine if you’re using (broad) IPA for Danish exclusively; it only becomes a problem when you also need to cater for an actual IPA /ð/ like the English one. (I agree that X-SAMPA is very user-unfriendly, though.)

Comment: Again, to close-voters: how is this a language-specific grammar and usage question? It's a question about how to transcribe a particular sound in IPA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_phonology) says "/ð/ – the so-called 'soft d' (Danish: *blødt d*) – is a velarized laminal alveolar approximant **[ð̠˕ˠ]**", citing Basbøll (2005), Grønnum (2003), and Ladefoged & Maddieson (1996).

Comment: is the IPA right here? I'd expect a velarised laminal alveolar approximant to be [ð̻̞ˠ]. This seems to use the retracted rather than laminal diacritic and have the lowered diacritic (used to show an approximant) following rather than properly stacked

Comment: looking on the wiki talk page, it looks like the lack of stacking is a deliberate style choice on wikipedia (even though I believe it is not proper to the IPA) as noted by you it turns out, but the use of a retracted diacritic rather than a laminal one is odd given the description

Comment: @Tristan [ð] is dental so the retracted diacritic makes sense. [ð̠˕ˠ] is indeed the transcription Basbøll and Grønnum give (though with different diacritic-stacking practices). The IPA doesn't specify apicality/laminality in the values of the coronal symbols (see the Principles of the IPA, reprinted in IPA Handbook Appendix 1), so noting the laminality is not a must.

Comment: sure, my question isn't so much why this transcription, but the transcription and description do not match. If laminal is specified in the description it ought to be in the transcription too (although if it is also in the sources, I understand why wikipedia can't change that)

Comment: @Tristan I'm saying they do match. [ð] is dental, not alveolar, hence the retracted diacritic.

Comment: I was mostly thinking of the common (but loose) usage of ð̞ for a non-rhotic alveolar approximant. You are right though, in narrow transcription (like this) this is not appropriate and the retracted diacritic is necessary. The descriptions still do *not* match though. If the laminality is noteworthy enough to make the description in words it ought to be included in the transcription, and if it isn't noteworthy enough to appear in the transcription, it shouldn't appear in the words

Comment: I do appreciate though that this is the transcription given by Basbøll & Grønnum, and not your own, so this is no longer really relevant to the quality of this answer, but different level of specificity between the words and transcription seems a poor choice to me

Answer (score 3):

This gets in to the difference between phonetic and phonological descriptions

The phoneme in question is generally called /ð/. The issue is that the precise phonetic details of how this phoneme is produced, differ quite a lot from prototypical [ð] (which is why English-speakers generally hear it as closer to our /l/ than our /ð/)

As Nardog says in their answer (citing Basbøll (2005), Grønnum (2003), and Ladefoged & Maddieson (1996) via [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_phonology)), this phoneme is pronounced as a velarised laminal alveolar approximant so if you need a precise *phonetic* transcription, [ð̠̻̞ˠ] would be appropriate

Note: wikipedia gives the phonetic transcription as [ð̠˕ˠ] (with no laminal diacritic, despite this being specified in the description of the sound in words, and also rendered with the lowered diacritic following rather than stacked)

Comment: The version you give here is a velarised laminal _dental_ approximant, which the soft d is not – you need the retracted symbol to make it alveolar. The alveolar place of articulation is essential, but the laminality isn’t really – that is, pronouncing it apically still produces something that sounds like a soft d, but pronouncing it dentally produces a sound that is audibly different and doesn’t sound like a natural soft d.

Comment: good point at least in narrow transcription as here. More loosely, when I've seen ð̞ used it's been to refer to an alveolar approximant rather than a dental one, despite that strictly not being how its defined (likewise, see the way that [a] is often used as mid, with [æ] as fully open in the position [a] is officially defined as occupying). I've edited the retracted diacritic into my transcription, and changed my note on the wikipedia form to note only that the laminality is not specified (and the lowered diacritic is following not stacked)

Comment: not only English-speakers. As a German, I hear (and try to pronounce) it as a mix of /l/ and /d/ (and not close to anything English)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In my experience, it is very common for speakers of many different languages to hear the soft d as an l or l-like sound. The problem is when they then also _produce_ it as such, because that actually hinders intelligibility: Danes tend to hear the ‘l-like sound’ produced by such as people as an actual l, a different phoneme, so they’ll hear _rude_ (window pane) as _rulle_ (roll). Generally speaking, it’s better in terms of comprehension for non-native speakers to approximate a lazy [ð] than any kind of l-like sound.

Comment: this sort of mismatched perceptions is responsible for a lot of confusions between languages tbh. Mandarin speakers tend to hear English /l/ & /ɹ/ as Mandarin /l/, whilst English speakers hear Mandarin /ʐ/ (pinyin <r>) as /ɹ/ meaning to English speakers it sounds like Mandarin-speakers just obstinately refuse to use /ɹ/ despite being able to produce it (I assume there is an inverse problem as well with English-speaking Mandarin students not being perceived as distinguishing /l/ & /ʐ/ because the students are making a distinction the Mandarin speakers just are not used to listening for)